# What is wrong with this code? VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

The value of the cell is always "error" no matter if the condition is true or not. I've tried using else but it doesn't work either.

```
Sub ejer_4()
    Cells(3, 1).Value = "hola"
    For i = 2 To 21:
        If Int(Cells(i, 3).Value) <> Int(Cells(i + 1, 3).Value) - 1 Then
            Cells(3, 1).Value = "Error"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are only changing the value of one cell (`Cells(3, 1)`), therefore, if the condition is true *at least once*, the cell value will be set to "Error" even if the condition is false for the rest of the 19 times.

Comment: ^^ You may want to increment the 3 in side of Cell(3,1)

Answer (score 0):

I think that should solve your problem:

```
Sub ejer_4()
    For i = 2 To 21:
        If Int(Cells(i, 3).Value) <> Int(Cells(i + 1, 3).Value) - 1 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = "Error"
        Else
            Cells(i, 1).Value = "hola"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You problem is that you loop thorugh range of cells, but after checking condition you write into one cell. So, this cell will contain oonly the result of the last check. Previous values will be simply overwritten.

Comment: thanks but change the value of the cell (3,1) not (i,1). However it got me closer to working this out